# how to use multiple left panels in nativedroid2

Tags: cordova, nativedroid

how can i use multiple left penal in one html file without errors my code

```
    <!-- panel left -->
        <div data-role="panel"  id="leftpanel" data-display="overlay" data-position-fixed="true" >

        <div class='nd2-sidepanel-profile wow fadeInDown' style="background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 112, 229, 0.4), rgba(0, 112, 229, 0.76));">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-xs-4 center-xs'>
                        <div class='box'>
                            <img class="profile-thumbnail" src="img/avathar.jpg" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-xs-8'>
                        <div class='box profile-text' style="color: black">
                            <strong style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="sprofilen2"> </strong>
                            <span class='subline' id="stype2" style="font-size: 17px;"></span>
                              <a  class ="stud"   style="color: white" ><span>  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 15px;">create </i> 
            Update Profile &ensp;</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/other.js"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript">
  function suser1() {
      document.getElementById("sprofilen2").innerHTML = window.localStorage.getItem('first_name1')+" "+window.localStorage.getItem('last_name1');
  document.getElementById("stype2").innerHTML= window.localStorage.getItem('user_type');

  }
</script>


            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
            <li><a href="#" class="viewjob" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">View Jobs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="viewment"  data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">View Mentors</a></li>


                <li><a href="#btitest" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Browse Training Institutes</a></li>
                </ul>



                <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" data-iconpos="right">
                <h3>My Requests</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                    <li><a href="#studreqjob1" data-ajax='false'>Post a Job</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#studreqproj" data-ajax='false'>Post for Project Assistance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#studreqtrain" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Post for Training</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"  data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">View Reponses</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Posted Job Requests</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"  data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Posted Project Assistance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Posted Training Requests</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        <ul data-role="listview" >
                <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">My Connections</a></li>

            </ul>


            <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-d" data-iconpos="right">
                <h3>My Preferences</h3>
                <ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false">
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false'>Mentors</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false'>Training Institutes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Change Password</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>




        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                <li><a href="#" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Contact Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pageone" data-ajax='false' data-icon="false">Logout</a></li>

            </ul>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/viewjob.js"> </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/viewmentor.js"> </script>
        </div>
        <!-- /panel left -->
```

can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask